# Php array sort by date after merge

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi i have an array which is combinations of 2 separate array producing same result, following are my array after merge :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 16
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_created] => 20130227095010

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 15
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_created] => 20130227101734

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 16
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_created] => 20130227094856

        )

)
```

From here onwards how can i sort again based on date_created desc or asc without using previously 2 arrays which i used to merge?

Update:
previous array result

array1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 15
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_created] => 20130227101734


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 16
            [user_id] => 2
            [date_created] => 20130227094856

        )

)
```

array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 16
            [user_id] => 3
            [date_created] => 20130227095010

        )

)
```

How can i use loop within these function to extract date_created for each of above arrays

```
usort($array,function($a, $b) { return $a['date_created'] - $b['date_created']; });
```

Comment: array_map is used to apply a function to each element of the array, not sorting the array itself

Answer (score 2):

Very easy with something like [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
usort($array,
      function($a, $b) { return $a['date_created'] - $b['date_created']; });
```

Comment: The `date_created` key of `$a` and `$b` should be compared.

Comment: @Matthew Whoops, I missed that somehow :)

Comment: @alex is there away to sort after merge without using previously 2 arrays used to merge?

Comment: @zlippr I'm not using two arrays.

Comment: @alex how can i use loop to get $a['date_created'] - $b['date_created'] since for me it looks like this $a[$i]['date_created'] - $b[$i]['date_created'] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own **sort function callback** and use it with the `usort` method.
There is need to re-use your first 2 arrays.

```
usort($yourMergedArray, yourCallBackSort);
```

and

```
function yourCallBackSort($firstEntry, $secondEntry)
{
    // Do some stuff to compare your values and return -1, 0 or 1
    // depend if $firstEntry id <, = or > to $secondEntry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sort = array();
foreach($your_combined_array as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['date_created'][$k] = $v['date_created'];
}

array_multisort($sort['date_created'], SORT_DESC, $your_combined_array);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($your_combined_array);
```